# Missing class attribute when calling other method in class

Tags: python, class-method, class-attributes

I'm a novice at all this stuff so please go easy on me!

I wrote a class to compute various vector results.  Several methods call on other methods within the class to construct the results.  Most of this works fine, except for a peculiar problem.  When I call one method from another method, the attribute for that method is somehow removed or missing and I get the error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dot_prod', even though the method 'dot_prod' is defined in the class.  The only way I found to get around this was to establish a new instance of the object using the returned result of the original method call.  In my code, I included both the problem code and workaround by comment switches, as well as comments in context to try to explain the issue.

```
from math import sqrt, acos, pi

class Vector:

def __init__(self, coordinates):
    try:
        if not coordinates:
            raise ValueError
        self.coordinates = tuple([x for x in coordinates])
        self.dimension = len(coordinates)

    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError('The coordinates must be nonempty')

    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError('The coordinates must be an iterable')


def scalar_mult(self, c):
    new_coordinates = [c*x for x in self.coordinates]
    return new_coordinates


def magnitude(self):
    coord_squared = [x**2 for x in self.coordinates]
    return sqrt(sum(coord_squared))


def normalize(self):
    try:
        mag = self.magnitude()
        norm = self.scalar_mult(1.0/mag)
        return norm

    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 'Divide by zero error'


def dot_prod(self, v):
    return sum([x*y for x,y in zip(self.coordinates, v.coordinates)])


def angle(self, v):

## This section below is identical to an instructor example using normalized unit
## vectors but it does not work, error indication is 'dot_prod' not
## valid attribute for list object as verified by print(dir(u1)). Instructor is using v2.7, I'm using v3.6.2.
## Performing the self.normalize and v.normalize calls removes the dot_prod and other methods from the return.
## My solution was to create new instances of Vector class object on  self.normalize and v.normalize as shown below:
##        u1 = self.normalize()    # Non working case
##        u2 = v.normalize()       # Non working case
    u1 = Vector(self.normalize())
    u2 = Vector(v.normalize())

    unit_dotprod = round((u1.dot_prod(u2)), 8)

    print('Unit dot product:', unit_dotprod)

    angle = acos(unit_dotprod)
    return angle

#### Test Code #####

v1 = Vector([-7.579, -7.88])
v2 = Vector([22.737, 23.64])


print('Magnitude v1:', v1.magnitude())
print('Normalized v1:', v1.normalize())
print()

print('Magnitude v2:', v2.magnitude())
print('Normalized v2:', v2.normalize())
print()
print('Dot product:', v1.dot_prod(v2))
print('Angle_rad:', v1.angle(v2))
```

The method 'angle(self, v)' is where the problem lies as far as I can tell, the comment notes in the code explains a bit more.  The variables u1 and u2 have a comment switch to toggle between, you'll see that in the working case, I created the new instances of the Vector object.  I simply do not know what is the reason why the attributes are missing from the original method calls.  The next line when u1.dot_prod(u2) is called is where the trace back error manifests, 'dot_prod' is missing from the attributes as verified by doing dir(u1) in the non-working case.

Appreciate the insights people have here.  I don't know the technical jargon very well so hopefully I can follow along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to pass in a list instead of a Vector to your `dot_prod` method (at command `u2 = v.normalize()`; the return object from that method is a list). Your issue, I think, is that you assumed that `u2` would attach as an attribute to the class, but you must call `self` as some point to do that. There are two correct ways to call a method and reattach the output as an attribute:

**(1)** You can call it after the class is instantiated (created) like so:

```
    vec = Vector([-7.579, -7.88])
    vec.normal_coords = vec.normalize()
```

This approach works better if you aren't expecting to need to do it for every Vector instance, and if you don't need to use the attribute in a bunch of other methods. Since you need the normalized coordinates to find the angle, I would instead recommend:

**(2)** Attaching as an attribute during instantiation (long code below, to fully show how this would work):

```
from math import sqrt, acos, pi

class Vector(object):

    def __init__(self, coordinates):
        try:
            if not coordinates:
                raise ValueError
            self.coordinates = tuple([x for x in coordinates])
            self.dimension = len(coordinates)

            # Next line is what you want - and it works, even though
            # it *looks like* you haven't defined normalize() yet :)
            self.normalized = self.normalize()

        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('The coordinates must be nonempty')

        except TypeError:
            raise TypeError('The coordinates must be an iterable')

   [...]

    def dot_prod(self, v):
        # v is class Vector here and in the angle() method
        return sum([x*y for x,y in zip(self.normalized, v.normalized)])


    def angle(self, v):
        unit_dotprod = round((self.dot_prod(v)), 8)

        print('Unit dot product:', unit_dotprod)
        angle = acos(unit_dotprod)

        return angle
```

Comment: thanks for comments.  I changed the list to a tuple in the .normalize function call.  So now the dot_prod method is passed the tuple instead of a list, but the problem is that the 'dot_prod' attribute is still missing from u1 and u2 = v.normalize() calls.  The change you made to dot_prod call "works" in that the code does not crash, but the math is off and this is the reason you are seeing the ValueError as the dot product returns a wrong value .  v.normalize scales the vector but unfortunately, the 'dot_prob' attribute is still missing from the object.  Try dir(u2).

Comment: Ah, yes, you are absolutely right - in my haste I failed to notice that you were wanting to pass in normalized coordinates to the dot product for angle. It's been a while since I dealt with vectors :) The short answer is you are kind of trying to attach `normalize` as both a method and an outside functions and classes don't really work like that (although you *can* call methods inside your initialization and reattach the answer as an attribute, which I think might be what you actually want). I'll update my answer when I have a bit more time

Comment: @Bill, please change indents as suggested - otherwise the code in your question is not valid.

Comment: Regarding the indentation, in my IDE it is all well, but when I pasted it here, the formatting was wonky so the only way I could get it to post cleanly in the code block was to remove the def indents.  I followed the directions to indent 4 spaces before pasting but it wasn't nice.  I thought I could just cleanly copy and paste but for some reason it wasn't clean.  If I'm missing something in the process, please let me know, thanks.

Comment: @HFBrowning, thanks for your valuable feedback.  I made your proposed edits, and it was much closer to what was needed.  The additional change was to replicate dot_prod() to dot_prod_unit() which is the special case needed for the angle function.  See the edits above.

Comment: @HFBrowning, the separation of dot_prod functions was due to the need for generalized dot product for any 2 vectors vs 2 unit vectors for angle calc.  Unrelated, I did notice that the self.normalize() function is not available to call from outside the class.  I surmise that it is because it is now used in the constructor and probably causes conflict otherwise.  No big deal, I just called the variable self.normalized instead of the function to get the actual vector.  Thanks for your diligence to help this noob along!

Comment: @Bill, I rejected your edit simply because my answer was intended to help your understanding, and I think it serves its purpose to the community as a reference better if I leave it as is currently. What you're getting into now has to do more with design decisions - you can write any code many different ways to achieve the same end :) Hopefully however I was able to illustrate to you why you were having trouble. If you believe I answered your question you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark.